# Call MVC web API controller method from client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to consume/call an MVC Web API controller method, which will be used to upload a file. I am struggling to call it from my MVC controller.

Here's my code for the API Controller

```
public class ImportController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool PutImportFile(byte[] fileToBeImported, string nameOfTheFileToBeImported)
    {   
        // I am doing file saving stuff here             
    }
}
```

I have tested the file saving part by changing the method to HttpGet and its working when I called it directly from the browser. I removed the parameters for that.

However, I am not able to figure out how to call it from a client.

I have tried below.

```
public class ImportFileModel
{
    public byte[] FileToBeImported { get; set; }

    public string NameOfTheFileToBeImported { get; set; }
}
```

The below code will accept a file from the browser uploaded by user and post it to the API controller to save the file.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Upload()
{
    byte[] file;
    string fileName = string.Empty;

    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            fileName = Request.Files[0].FileName;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Request.Files[0].InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                file = ms.ToArray();
            }

            //To do: get url from configuration
            string url = "http://localhost:(port)/api/Import/PutImportFile";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));

                ImportFileModel request = new ImportFileModel
                {
                    FileToBeImported = file,
                    NameOfTheFileToBeImported = fileName
                };

                MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
                var result = await client.PostAsync(url, request, bsonFormatter);

                HttpResponseMessage response = result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // exception handling here
        }
    }

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It ends up in an exception at the last line.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Throwing `404 not found` error.

I have also tried the same from a console application using HttpWebRequest. It also throws the same error.

Comment: Try to define route explicitly, may be that works.

Comment: @MUT I believe, you are right. As it worked after making the parameters bundle into a single object. I will also try and make an explicit route definition and see if it works that way as well. But I wonder, how it works in normal MVC controllers without defining explicit routes and not in Web API controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Web API method `PutImportFile` is setup to receive two values, not a single model; hence, your `HttpClient` call is not recognized (no matching route found). Change your Web API method to receive a model:

```
public class ImportController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public bool PutImportFile(ImportFileModel fileInfo)
    {   
        //Your code to save the file...            
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it still does not reach the method. Error type has changed from 404 to 500, however, it doesn't reach the controller.

Comment: Interesting, it looks like the method is found then, but something goes wrong. If you breakpoint at the entry to the method, does it hit?

Comment: It worked!!! I had added a section in web config from other questions from SO. `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` in `<system.webServer>`. Removed it and it worked! Thanks a ton! Never thought it would be routing issue.

Comment: Awesome! Test it from the browser too - you may need to make a change to how JSON is being sent in, since the method is expecting a single object now.

Comment: Luckily, that part is still pending to write; so I will work on sending a single JSON object. You made my day! Cheers!